# How to delete customer on stripe using PHP custom curl?

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments

[image: code]

The picture above is the result of my code. How can I delete it? I don't want to use library, I want to learn how to use the PHP curl before using the library.

```
<?php
function DeleteCustomer() {

    $array = array(
        'id' => 'cus_AKjDJGDrHovimg'
        );

    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($array));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $output=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
     $output = json_decode($output,true);
    return $output;
 }

$a = DeleteCustomer();
print_r($a);

?>
```

Thank you for those who will answer.

Comment: why `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to delete stripe customer using this code. :D

```
<?php
function DeleteCustomer() {

    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_AKjDJGDrHovimg');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_decode($result);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;

 }

$a = DeleteCustomer();
echo'<pre>';
print_r($a);

?>
```